# How can I draw this shape in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, drawing, gradient

I would like to draw a shape that looks exactly like this, with the same gradient fill:

[image: Swirly icon]

using only XAML.

- The radius of the inner circle needs to be configurable.
- The radius of the outer circle needs to be configurable.
- The width of the gap at the top needs to be configurable.
- The white color needs to be transparent.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Please Take a look at [this article](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Another homework question....?

Comment: @HighCore The take shouldn't be capitalized. (about as helpful as your answer)

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow that's not an answer. It's a recommendation just in case you don't want to get many downvotes here. Post some relevant XAML.

Comment: @BahriGungor - No. I don't want to spend 3 hours re-inventing the wheel if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508398/draw-a-circle-in-wpf-using-minwidth-height-2-as-radius

Comment: @HighCore - It's a perfectly reasonable question. If you don't like it you don't have to answer it do you.

Comment: @Bahri Gungor - It requires the intersection of two shapes on a third and then an angular gradient - I think that is a bit tricky, which was why I asked for some advice. You could try stop wasting your own time and everybody else's.